# Haptic Longpress on Reorderable List

Tags: flutter, haptic-feedback, reorderable-list

On an android, how can I cause a vibrate on the long press of a reorderable list item? I have tried using gesture detector on the item and it disables the ability to reorder the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `proxyDecorator`'s child in a stateful widget that calls `HapticFeedback.lightImpact();` in its `initState()` to vibrate when the user picks up the widget. To vibrate on release, call `HapticFeedback.lightImpact();` in the `ReorderableListView`'s `onReorder` callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
 ReorderableListView(
 ...
 onReorderStart: (int index) {
    HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
},
```